# iOS Share extension not showing for URLs and Text

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-extensions, ios8-share-extension

So I have made a hybrid application using react-native and I had no issues setting up share for android, but in iOS I am not able to make my application appear on the share list.
I need Apple Music or any application that shares a URL to be able to share to my extension.

I have added the following settings to my info.plist for the share extension

[image]

If I mention the NSExtensionActivationRule for an Image, I am able to see my application on the list but it is not working for URLs at all. Am I missing something in the setup ?

Update:

I am using MacOS 10.15 and Xcode 12.4
The share extension is working as expected on iOS 14.2 on an iPhone 8 and it is not working as expected in iOS 14.4.2 on an iPhone X

Found more information on Apple Developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662671?page=2

it seems to be getting fixed if you restart the device, this is an open issue and appeared first in iOS 14.4.1

found another issue with a similar problem
[Share extension - App not showing in share menu on first attempt since iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64166595/share-extension-app-not-showing-in-share-menu-on-first-attempt-since-ios-14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be fixed since I upgraded my Mac OS to the latest version BigSur, Share extensions are showing up normally again

Answer (score -1):

To add more apps for share sheet, add external application query schema code in. your info.plist, like below.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>mailto</string>
        <string>twitter</string>
        <string>viber</string>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
        <string>wechat</string>
        <string>line</string>
        <string>instagram</string>
        <string>instagram-stories</string>
        <string>kakaotalk</string>
        <string>mqq</string>
        <string>vk</string>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
        <string>googlephotos</string>
        <string>ha</string>
        <string>yammer</string>
    </array>
```

And use **Share** from *react-native*

```
try {
  const result = await Share.share(
    {
      message: `My message`,
      url: urlLink,
      title: `My title`,
    },
    {
      subject: `My subject`,
    },
  );

  if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
    if (result.activityType) {
    } else {
    }
  } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
  }
} catch (error) {
  alert(error.message);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry but I'm looking for a solution from the other side, sharing data from other applications to my app